# apt-get problem

Tags: apt

every time I try to install something by writing `sudo apt-get install` in the terminal, I have always the same answer :

```
E: The package linux-image-3.0.0-32-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I can't remove and reinstall this package (same error) and I don't know how I can correct this error. Thank you very much!

Comment: Reinstall your system, packages with the kernel is marked so that it can not re-install or remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and try again.

If this fails, your best option would be to back up and reinstall Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The package named in the error log is the package containing the Linux kernel currently installed on your system.

SO it seems like your system is broken. I don't know any other way to fix this than to reinstall your system. There may be other's, but it's safest to reinstall, so you get a clean and fresh system.

If you got this problem since installation, I'd check whether the ISO file you got isn't damaged (redownload, compare md5 sums)